# Undefined Variable in Ajax from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried different ways to make this work but it is still not working. `data[0].urgency` is undefined. I tried to stringify data but a bunch of \n in between the result (see below).

Thank you in advance.

My ajax code:

```
function ajaxCall() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../nav/post_receiver.php",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data.length);
          console.log(data[0].urgency);
        }
      });
    }
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    ob_start(); 
    require_once('../../mysqlConnector/mysql_connect.php');
    $results = array();
    $query="SELECT COUNT(initID) AS count, urgency, crime, initID, TIMESTAMPDIFF( minute,dateanalyzed,NOW()) AS minuteDiff FROM initialanalysis WHERE commanderR='0' AND stationID='{$_SESSION['stationID']}';";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $count = $row['count'];
        $urgency = $row['urgency'];
        $crime = $row['crime'];
        $initID = $row['initID'];
        $minuteDiff = $row['minuteDiff'];

        $results[] = array("count" => $count, "urgency" => $urgency, "crime" => $crime, "initID" => $initID, "minuteDiff" => $minuteDiff);
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Result of PHP:

> [{"count":"9","urgency":"Low","crime":"Firearm","initID":"6","minuteDiff":"4743"}]

I think the result is in wrong format? I'm not sure.

This is the result of `console.log(data)`, there is a comment tag of html and I don't know why:

```
 <!--  -->
[{"count":"9","urgency":"Low","crime":"Firearm","initID":"6","minuteDiff":"4761"}]
```

Comment: add `dataType:"json"` to your ajax or add `data = $.parseJSON(data)` in ajax success

Comment: If you cut out the AJAX request the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/a07ooxuj/. This means that either the request is failing, or you're not returning the data you think you are. Either way you need to check the console to see what the exact response is

Comment: What does `data.length` actually return? If you do `console.log( typeof data )` what do you get ?

Comment: @adeneo why would  `data[0].urgency` is undefined when I print it in the console?

Comment: it should work with intelligent guess, but have you tried to set the data type? plus, you should console.log `data` and paste it here to see where the problem comes from

Comment: Unless the server is sending the proper headers for JSON, jQuery doesn't guess but just assumes it plain text.

Comment: `When I tried to JSON.stringify(data) the data, this is the result` you don't want stringify, you want the opposite, `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Kaddath I have edited my question with the result of `console.log(data)`

Comment: You seem to be echoing more than just the JSON, and that means it can't be parsed as JSON. You have to figure out where the HTML comes from.

Comment: @adeneo i tried to find it, but there is no comment tag in my codes

Answer (score 0):

Update your ajax call like this

```
function ajaxCall() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../nav/post_receiver.php",
    success: function(data) {
      data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data.length);
      console.log(data[0].urgency);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it shows an Unexpected SyntaxError

Comment: data= jQuery.parseJSON(data); it's work, Check php code it's php error

Comment: I tried to add `dataType:"JSON"` but it doesnt print anything.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser for validate the json response like JSON.parse

```
function ValidateJsonString(str) {
    try {

        JSON.parse(str);

    } catch (e) {

        return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```